# What type of grammar is "get someone shot"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know we can use the structure "get + object + past participle" to express accidents or misfortunes happening to us. But how's it different in an imperative? What does it mean when someone says, "Get your boss shot"?

Answer (score 2):

I have only ever heard of this particular phrase to describe someone getting in serious trouble. It can also be said literally.

For example *Don't go downtown at night you're liable to get yourself shot* would be a relatively informal way to express the *danger* of the area (in this case downtown). In this sentence *shot* is literal in the sense the area (downtown) is being described as a high crime area.

Another figurative example could be yours but some context is needed. *Don't tell the VP about this you'll get your boss shot*. In this case shot is (hopefully) not literally and simply acting as an intensifier on the trouble that your boss could get into.

Answer (score 0):

'Shot' is the complement of 'get' and the state of the object. The state is the result of 'get'